# Automatic Calculation with given numbers

Tags: vb.net

I would like to make CPU to calculate declared result from the given numbers that are also declared.

```
So far: 

    Dim ArrayOperators() As String = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "(", ")"}
    Dim GlavniBroj As Integer = GBRnb() 'Number between 1 and 999 that CPU needs to get from the numbers given below:

    Dim OsnovniBrojevi() As Integer = {OBRnb(), OBRnb(), OBRnb(), OBRnb()} '4 numbers from 1 to 9
    Dim SrednjiBroj As Integer = SBRnb() '1 number, 10, 15 or 20 chosen randomly
    Dim KrajnjiBroj As Integer = KBRnb() '25, 50, 75 or 100 are chosen randomly

    Private Function GBRnb()
        Randomize()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((999 * Rnd()) + 1))
        Return value
    End Function

    Private Function OBRnb()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((9 * Rnd()) + 1))
        Return value
    End Function

    Private Function SBRnb()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((3 * Rnd()) + 1))
        If value = 1 Then
            Return 10
        ElseIf value = 2 Then
            Return 15
        ElseIf value = 3 Then
            Return 20
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function

    Private Function KBRnb()
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((4 * Rnd()) + 1))
        If value = 1 Then
            Return 25
        ElseIf value = 2 Then
            Return 50
        ElseIf value = 3 Then
            Return 75
        ElseIf value = 4 Then
            Return 100
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function
```

Is there any way to make a program to calculate GlavniBroj(that is GBRnb declared) with the help of the other numbers (also without repeating), and with help of the given operators? Result should be displayed in the textbox, in a form of the whole procedure of how computer got that calculation with that numbers and operators. I tried to make it work by coding operations one by one, but that's a lot of writing... I'm not looking exactly for the code answer, but mainly for the coding algorithm.  Any idea? Thanks! :)

Comment: Look into the [`Random`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwiqydPCsp3JAhVH2GMKHZ4KAHs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.random(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGSBmllDVxqPe0wWaFJaXc5lMWZ8Q&sig2=QeywtkU-CmUyEQlF1kQz1w&bvm=bv.107763241,d.cGc) class.

Comment: In `KBRnb()` you could just `Return value * 25` instead of all that If...ElseIf...

Comment: Well I am not really pro in programming... :)